# Why does Table Definitions Opened differ this much between cluster nodes?

Tags: mysql, percona, galera

I have a Percona/Galera cluster and see this when i monitor the different cluster nodes. What does this really mean? And is this something erroneous that needs to be taken care of?

This is how one of the nodes looks like.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Cluster node 1]

All other nodes in the cluster looks like this
[image: The other cluster nodes]

Comment: One factor could be tables opened for *reading*, which would only be opened on the server being queried.  Another could be writes that were rolled back, since Galera replicates transactions among servers at commit time, not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the 'one' node?  That is, you are treating it as the only Master?  Galera does "Row Based Replication", so it probably does not need to open the table definition on the 'Slaves'?

Do you have the same values for `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table%';` on all nodes?

Comment: Yep, they are exactly the same.

Well it could have been that one we bootstrapped the cluster with.

Comment: Are all writes going to one node?

Comment: Otherwise they are all load balanced so number of connections should be similar for all the nodes.

Comment: "Connections" and "tables opened" are separate things.

Comment: I might have found it. Could a SHOW CREATE TABLE spark a 'Table Definitions Opened'?

Comment: The `STATUS` value `Opened_table_definitions` increments by 1 when doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- _if_ that table in not already in the `table_open_cache`.  So, how many tables do you have?  What is the setting of the `VARIABLE` `table_open_cache` on each machine?  And why are you doing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so often, apparently on only one node?

Comment: Note:  Some 3rd party software products do "dumb" things like `SHOW CREATE TABLE` before every statement.  Are you calling MySQL directly, or using 3rd party software?

Comment: Right on. `table_open_cache = 2000` so i doubled it and the charts flat lined directly. We do some integrity tests on the databases as a last line of defence against the developers ;-) It checks the table structures so they haven't been changed and that they are up to date.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 50 checks/sec is possibly a big burden on the system.

Comment: Do the devs have `alter` and `create...` privileges?  Removing that would eliminate their ability to make changes?

Comment: No its just a check that checks a comment in each table with (show create table ) that checks the correlation between code-trunk and db. Unfortunately some "special" (severely above my paygrade) devs have access to everything. I see a typo in my earlier answer it was the `table_definition_cache` I changed. Not the table_open_cache. Yep, me and my company have a lot more to learn in all this. Thank alot. It was appreciating .